# Trying to populate an html table using Jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I need to know how can i add a row in this table for each one of the values of the checked checkboxes.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="sel_articulos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I'm saving a list of checked checkboxes with this code in an array.

```
$('#modalarticulos').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {;
    var sel_articulos = $("input[name='check_art']:checked").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(sel_articulos);
    showSels();
})
```

tried with this method but i get all the values from the array in the response

```
var tbody = $('#sel_articulos tbody');
var props = ["id"];
$.each(sel_articulos, function(i, sel_articulo) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
        $('<td>').html(sel_articulos).appendTo(tr);  
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```

I.E: If i select 5 values i get this on every row of my table.
112113114115117

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Are you sure that semicolon at the end of the first line of your JS should be there?

Comment: i made it work, just had to set a var x and increase it to call the sel_articulos var in the position sel_articulos[x]